# [gcloud compute ssh]: --ssh-flag param not working

Tags: gcloud

In accordance with the docs, I'm attempting to pass additional flags to `gcloud compute ssh` using the `--ssh-flag` param as follows:

`gcloud compute ssh instance-name --ssh-flag="-t tmux a"`

I'm getting the following error:

> /usr/bin/ssh: illegal option --

- OSX 10.11.3
- Google Cloud SDK 94.0.0

Any ideas?

I've double-checked the syntax, and it looks to be identical to the provided example in the docs. In the meantime, I'm able to use actual `ssh` to invoke the above command.

Answer (score 0):

You can use --dry-run to see what ssh command `gcloud compute ssh` is actually calling. Then you can just copy & paste that command and add the additional flags you want.

Answer (score 0):

Another answer: update gcloud by running `gcloud components update`. The latest version is 96.0.0 and it's very possible the --ssh-flag is a new addition.